# Where to connect thermostat C wire to Weil-McLain HE2 series 1 boiler

Tags: electrical

I have a Weil-McLain HE2 series 1 boiler and am attempting to attach a Honeywell RTH6500 wifi thermostat to the main floor. The house has 4 zones and therefor 4 separate thermostats. The main floor thermostat has an extra (green wire) in addition to a red and white at the thermostat. There is only heat, no AC, fueled by propane. I attached the thermostat on the main floor and with the Cwire attached to the neutral side of the external transformer, the thermostat powers up, but cycles off and on when calling for heat. There is an additional transformer inside the boiler unit with a pink and brown wire. Where should I attach the C wire at the boiler?[image]

Comment: What is the external transformer for, it doesn't appear on the schematic you included? From the schematic, it looks like one side of the transformer is grounded, so you *may* be able to attach `C` to ground. Though if there's a zone controller involved, all bets are off. You'll have to include the schematic for that as well.

Comment: It is attached and powered by the boiler switch. Then the hot end of the transformer, which actually shows 29 volts,  leads to each of the 4 valves and the control board where it shows Control 24VAC.

Comment: What model valves are you using? What is the volt-ampere (VA) rating of the external transformer?

Comment: Taco zone valve 571-2.  Screw #1 wire 26 volts connects to a wire where all 4 valve screw #1 are connected. Screw #2 wire is 26 volts and connects all valve screw#2 together and comes from the external transformer. Screw # 3 wire is neutral and connects all valve screw 3 together and comes from the external transformer. That transformer is a 40 amp.

Comment: I only want to add 1 wifi thermostat to one zone valve, doesn't it make sense to add that C wire to only that zone valve? Tried it, doesn't work. The thermostat blinks off and on.

Comment: Sorry the external transformer is 24V, 20VA.

Comment: If it's 24V-20VA it's way under powered.  According to the documentation, each zone valve is 0.9 amperes. That transformer is chugging just opening one valve.

Answer (score 1):

Both this document (PDF) and [this document (PDF)](http://s3.supplyhouse.com/product_files/571-2-brochure.pdf), say that one 24V-40VA transformer can only support 3 zone valves. Since you have 4 valves, you're over the recommended number of valves.  Once you added the demand of the WiFi thermostat, you likely overwhelmed the transformer. The answer here, may be to install an additional transformer.

There's a diagram in the [second document](http://s3.supplyhouse.com/product_files/571-2-brochure.pdf), that shows how to wire in an additional transformer. This document also has a good explanation of how the valve actually works, which might be worth a read.

> [image: 571-2 Taco-Zone valve additional zone wiring]

Based on these documents, a WiFi thermostat should be wired in like this.

[image: 571-2 Taco-Zone valve additional zone wiring Wifi thermostat]

Based on the [your description of the wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/74882/where-to-connect-thermostat-c-wire-to-weil-mclain-he2-series-1-boiler/74928#comment102194_74882), it sounds like it's a bit different than that of the documentation. Incorrectly wired valves might also be the problem. Based on the documentation, terminals `1` and `2` are connected through a heater, while terminals `2` and `3` are connected only when the valve is open.

When the thermostat closes (calls for heat), current flows from terminal `1`, through the heater, to terminal `2`. Once the valve opens, a contact allows current to flow between terminals `2` and `3`.  So basically energizing `1` and `2` opens the valve, and energizing `2` and `3` signals the boiler to circulate.

Comment: Good catch on the 3 valves per transformer. Is that why they have that second (external-outside the boiler) transformer? And should I change that out to a 24-40? And where would I connect that C common wire for that one zone valve?

Comment: @G.Merc According to the document, you should have 2 external transformers for the valves. And that's in addition to the one in the boiler.  So that's 3 total transformers.  If you look at the last image in my answer, the blue line represents the `C` wire.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. I'll give it a shot. I really appreciate all your time and responses. I'll let you know. Thank You.

Comment: Tester101- Do you think I can get away with swapping out that 24V-20VA with a 24-40VA? Do you think that would do it?

Comment: @G.Merc I'm just going off the documentation here, and it says you need two 24V-40VA transformers for your setup.

Comment: FYI- bought a 24VAC-40VA, and replaced the 24VAC-20VA. All symptoms are the same. All other zones can call for heat, simultaneously. But the wifi thermostat powers up and even recognizes the wifi in the house, but when it calls for heat, even with the other thermostats off, it blinks off and on and doesn't call for heat. White to red equals 24 volts, white to C wire equals 0. I also tried hooking that C wire to the other screw on the transformer, and it was completely dead even though it shows 24volts white to red and white to C wire.

Comment: FYI- bought a 24VAC-40VA, and replaced the 24VAC-20VA. All symptoms are the same. All other zones can call for heat, simultaneously. But the wifi thermostat powers up and even recognizes the wifi in the house, but when it calls for heat, even with the other thermostats off, it blinks off and on and doesn't call for heat. White to red equals 24 volts, white to C wire equals 0. I also tried hooking that C wire to the other screw on the transformer, and it was completely dead even though it shows 24volts white to red and white to C wire..... So I had that extra 24/20 transformer

Comment: And added it to the switch. I ran that C wire directly to it, alone, and it still didn't work. No power. So are you going to suggest buying another 24/40 and replacing the 24/20?

Comment: Like I said before, I think your valves are wired differently than in the documentation. Since I can't see, or inspect your wiring, I've provided about all the help I can. I don't know why you're checking the voltage between W and C.  Voltage between R and C should always be 24 volts, as that's where the thermostat is drawing power.

Comment: If everything is wired as it is in the diagram, the C wire should come off the 2 terminal (or the transformer wire that connects to the 2 terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution: added a 24VAC/20VA transformer. Wired it into the on/off switch on the side of the boiler. Needed 4 wires to the thermostat, but I only had a three, two of which ( red, white) were being used. So fished 2 more wires from the thermostat to the boiler. At the thermostat, removed the jumper between R and RC, and hooked one wire on RC. Hooked a second wire at C ( common). There were now 4 wires connected to the thermostat, R, RC, W, and C. At the boiler connected the two new wires to the new transformer, doesn't matter which sides. I now have 24 volts (actually like 28 but that's fine) to the R, C, and RC terminals at the thermostat. Works perfectly, Finished, End of Story.